# jQuery as function and Object, i.e. $() and $.()

Tags: javascript

How can a global object be programmed to be treated as a function and a object? Just like jQuery does (if I am correct?)

For example:

```
 X.foo = '';
```

and

```
 X('bar');
```

Comment: To be slightly more specific than the answers below, a function is just a type of object that is callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply define `X` and `X.foo` as you normally would, like this:

```
var X = function(a)
{
    return a * 2;
}
X.foo = function(a)
{
    return a + 1;
}

console.log(X(10));
console.log(X.foo(10));
```

Results in:

```
20
11
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JavaScript are objects like any other and can have arbitrary properties. For example:

```
function Test() {}

Test.someProp = "test";
```

You might think of these as class variables, depending on your point of view.

Witness:

```
Test instanceof Object // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function X(string){
    alert(string);
}

X.foo = 10;
alert(X.foo); // Alerts "10"
X('bar');     // Alerts "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Every function is an object in Javascript:

```
function f(x) {
    console.log(x);
}
f.foo = 1;
f('bar'); // 'bar
console.log(f.foo); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function X(name)
{
    if (name == 'bar')
    {
        // do so mething
    }
}
X.foo = "hello!";
```

Functions are objects in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(txt){

    alert(txt)

}
foo.text="bar"
alert(foo.text)       //will give you "bar"
foo("bar")            //will give you "bar" also
```